# How to remove a (group) of softwares that depend on one another?

Tags: yum

I would like for example to remove php and all it's components and extensions as seen in this picture, but instead of removing every software one by one, is there anyway *safe* I can remove them all using a single command?

[image]

Comment: Removing the lowest-common-denominator dependency would be a good start. In this case `php55w-common`, perhaps.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did. It only removed like 4 dependencies along with it. But there might be a might `grep` way to do this

Comment: Sure, you could ask to remove all packages of the form `php55w-*` if you want.

Comment: Oooh. I don't think this is a duplicate. The grep-based solution is dangerous. Better to use yum's own wildcards or in some cases `yum --setopt="clean_requirements_on_remove=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in CentOS, you could use the `yum` as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/354492).

```
yum remove $(yum list installed | grep php | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr "\n" " ")
```